# foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed connecting with pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm connecting the pivot table but it's constantly calling this error

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

This is column in question

```
$table->increments('id'); (the id which should be primary key)

$table->integer('qu', false); (the column that is connected to pivot table
```

This is in pivot table

```
        $table->integer('quick_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('quick_id')->references('qu')->on('speed')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `qu` needs to be unsigned or `quick_id` can't be unsigned.  You can't create a foreign key on 2 integer columns when one is unsigned and one isn't.

Comment: I added $table->integer('qu', false)->unsigned(); but it still calling the same error

Comment: It's possible if the migration already ran, it's not recreating that table.  You may have to rollback some migrations and try again.

Comment: i removed entire tables before running migrations again